# Using Messaging center xamarin forms PCL to set current objects value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a scenario where i create Entry Controls programmatically.

```
     foreach (var control in FormInfo.FormElementsInfo)
        {

       case "textbox":
                      //Some code
                      break;


       case "dropdown":

       Entry objDropdown = new Entry();
       objDropdown.HeightRequest = 40;
       objDropdown.StyleId = Convert.ToString(control.ElementId);
       objDropdown.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "ElementValue",BindingMode.TwoWay);
       objDropdown.BindingContext = control;
       layout.Children.Add(objDropdown);

       MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Picklists, string>(objDropdown, "PicklistSelected", (sender, arg) =>
        {
           objDropdown.Text = arg; 
    // I tried this too as this is two way binding. It didn't show the value. 

          //control.ElementValue = arg;



        } );
       break;
     }
```

If i click on any entry it will open me a list view. Once i select the option in the list view it will populate that data in the Entry.
But this should show the selected value only in the current entry but it is changing the value in all the entry's.

How to avoid this situation. I want the selected value to be populated only in the current entry.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

=== More clear question=====

If we create n number of Entry controls programmatically with 2 way binding . Is it possible to change the single entry value on selecting something in other page? If yes how to achieve this?

Comment: You're only showing a case for a single enrty. Are all your entries databound to the same value? If they're all bound to the same value then I would expect them all to reflect the change.

Comment: @Joshua
foreach (var control in FormInfo.FormElementsInfo)
   {  //Above case statement }. The above case statement is within this for loop and the everything is same. Each entry is bound to a separate object called Control. I tried to use the Delegate instead of Messaging center i have the same scenario with that as well.

Comment: Can you post the entire function? Without seeing the rest of the implementation I can only assume that the loop is iterating over all controls. I don't see how you're linking to the "selected" item in the list. You definitely shouldn't be updating your bindings in the for loop. If bind before then the value should just update.

Comment: @JoshuaPoling I have edited the question. Please let me know if this is clear.Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to find a control on a view based on its styleId?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in finding the control. This method is instantiating your view. When you're doing that you're setting the binding for each new Entry to "ElementValue" which I assume is a property of FormElementsInfo. Since they are all bound to the same property of the same instance then they all share the same value. Does this list dynamically change or do you always have a fixed number of entries?

Comment: ElementValue is a property in Control class. So its class or Binding Context  is different for each entry. But the problem is they are subscribed to the same event or subscriber. Thats why one textbox requests for value all the textbox's are getting that value. But i want only the current textbox to get the value.  How can i tell the subscriber about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141796/discussion-between-joshua-poling-and-newbieios).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thank you @Joshua Poling for taking time to help me.

I think MessagingCenter is not suitable for this approach.

I am assigning a unique styleId to each element that i create.That basically stores the position in the stack layout.

I have written a delegate which returns the selected value and also the position of the element. As the element is always an Entry that fires this event. I used the below code to achieve this.

Entry myentry = (Xamarin.Forms.Entry)layout.Children[src.ElementId];

Answer (score 0):

**FormInfo**

```
 public class FormInfo
{
    public List<FormsElementInfo> FormElementsInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**FormsElementInfo**

```
public class FormsElementInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _elementValue;
    public string ElementValue {
        get => _elementValue;
        set {
            if(_elementValue != value)
            {
                _elementValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ElementValue"));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Content Page**

```
 public class ListStackOverflow : ContentPage
{
    private FormInfo _info = new FormInfo
    {
        FormElementsInfo = new List<FormsElementInfo>()
        {
           new FormsElementInfo { ElementValue = "test 1"},
           new FormsElementInfo { ElementValue = "test 2"},
           new FormsElementInfo { ElementValue = "test 3"},
           new FormsElementInfo { ElementValue = "test 4"},
        }
    };
    private StackLayout _stack = new StackLayout();
    private List<string> _source = new List<string>
    {
        "output 1","output 2","output 3","output 4",
    };

    public ListStackOverflow()
    {
        //BindingContext = _info;

        foreach(var c in _info.FormElementsInfo)
        {
            Entry tempEntry = new Entry
            {
                HeightRequest = 40,
                Placeholder = c.ElementValue,
                BindingContext = c
            };
            tempEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "ElementValue");

            _stack.Children.Add(tempEntry);
        }
        ListView _lv = new ListView { ItemsSource = _source };
        _lv.ItemSelected += Lv_ItemSelected;


        _stack.Children.Add(_lv);

        Content = _stack;
    }

    private void Lv_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedElement = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var index = _source.IndexOf(selectedElement);
        var entry = _info.FormElementsInfo[index];
        entry.ElementValue = selectedElement;
    }
}
```

**Output**

Selecting the corresponding index in the listview will update "ElementValue" for the same index.

[image: Output]